# ¿Por qué existe el límite de 20 revisiones por día en las colas de revisión?

Tags: soporte, colas-de-revisión

Cuando alcanzamos los 500 puntos de [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), [obtenemos acceso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) a las [colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review), primero se desbloquean *primeras publicaciones* y *respuestas tardías*, eventualmente se desbloquean más cuando el usuario gana más [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

En varias ocasiones, he revisado 20 elementos en alguna cola y me pone un mensaje diciendo que vuelva en cierto tiempo, pasado ese tiempo será otro día en el tiempo UTC, pero  ¿Por qué existe este límite de revisiones por día? ¿Y con qué fin se implementó dicho límite?

[image: ¿Por qué existe el límite de 20 revisiones por día en las colas de revisión?]

Comment: Seguro que en meta en inglés o en alguna parte existe una respuesta correcta a esta pregunta, pero imagino que al menos uno de los motivos es evitar que puedas encontrar tus reportes o un reporte concreto en la lista. Por ejemplo si un amigo te dice "He reportado esta pregunta" no podrás ir a revisar ese reporte concreto saltándote todos los demás. Por otro lado, SO se rige por la opinión de la mayoría. Si podemos revisar infinitos reportes, los 2 o 3 primeros en abrir la cola serán los que tomen todas las decisiones... Así se reparte mucho más el trabajo

Comment: Interesante @Benito-B Hay poca información al respecto, lo que encontré hasta ahora solo fue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158335/daily-review-limit-exceeded Además, me hace mucho sentido lo que dices acerca de los reportes y lo del reparto de las tareas, muchas gracias por los comentarios

Comment: Por cierto, me encontré en esa misma situación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encuentro información adicional en el sitio meta en inglés, pero como se dijo en comentarios, esta es una restricción principalmente para:

- Evitar que se encuentren los reportes que uno mismo hace
- Evitar que una sola persona tome el control de toda una cola

Se entiende que las tareas de revisión deben ser repartidas entre distintos usuarios

Pero, ¿Por qué especificar una cantidad límite de revisiones para todas las colas?

En colas como *votos de cierre*, siempre hay muchas preguntas y 20 revisiones no bastarían

[image: ¿Por qué existe el límite de 20 revisiones por día en las colas de revisión?]

[image: ¿Por qué existe el límite de 20 revisiones por día en las colas de revisión?]

Podrían ampliarse el número de revisiones para una cola específica que esté "saturada" siempre (Ejemplo: Hasta 25 o 30 revisiones por día en votos de cierre)

**PD:** Este no sería el sitio para este tipo de peticiones, esta ya sería una pregunta de Meta general

**En resumen**, el límite se implementó con el fin de que un usuario no tome el control total de una fila de revisión y las tareas de revisión sean repartidas entre todos los usuarios de la comunidad

Además, las colas de revisión están diseñadas de manera que no se encuentren los reportes realizados por uno mismo, incluso teniendo revisiones restantes

*Gran parte de esta respuesta fue compuesta gracias al comentario de @Benito-B. Agradecido con su aporte*

Comment: En algunos casos se ha ampliado a 40 para que las colas se reduzcan un poco.